# iOS- UITapGestureRecognizer Gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I want to add click event in my custom header class. 
Following is my code. When I click on Header area it gives EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];

    }

    return self;
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

    //Do stuff here...
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Comment: try doing the allocation code in `viewDidLoad`. after super

Comment: Getting [_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint handleSingleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c70800 when did in viewdidload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your custom header class is subclass of `UIView`  means then use `self` instead of `self.view`

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[recognizer.view superview]];

//Do stuff here...
}
```

Comment: The application is not coming in the handleSingleTap function.

Comment: Add that code in view did load and also you set user interaction for self.view

Comment: If your custom header class is UIView subclass means then use self instead of self.view

Comment: Actually this is a view controller. I want to add a tap gesture into its view. I am using it as a UITable view Header.

Comment: why are you going for UIViewController class to add subview. you can use UIView itself

Comment: If it is viewController class then you should have access it by something like creating object for custom header class. if yes you add gesture recognizer in that tableview class instead of custom header class

Answer (score 1):

```
//At View did load
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

- (void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
   //addcodehere
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helpful for you......

```
 {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    /* Create the Tap Gesture Recognizer */
    self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                 initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTaps:)];
   self.tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;

    self.tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
}
- (void) handleTaps:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)paramSender
{
    NSUInteger touchCounter = 0; for (touchCounter = 0;
                                      touchCounter < paramSender.numberOfTouchesRequired;
                                      touchCounter++)
    {
        CGPoint touchPoint =
        [paramSender locationOfTouch:touchCounter inView:paramSender.view];
        NSLog(@"Touch #%lu: %@",(unsigned long)touchCounter+1, NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing in init method try to do in ViewDidLoad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerTap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerTap];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

And include this method in class extension as,

```
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer ;
```

Or write it before viewDidLoad.

Comment: Getting [_UIScrollViewAutomaticContentSizeConstraint handleSingleTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c70800 when did in viewdidload

Comment: included. but noting happens.